# Linked Images in wordpress live site are redirecting to localhost

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I successfully transferred my WordPress website to live site. Every thing is working correctly except some links and linked images. They are still redirecting to localhost upon click. 
I tried this query 
 `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content,"http://localhost/wordpress","MY LIVE SITE'S URL")`  
I am not expert at MySQL. so i just ran this query in my phpmyadmin panel's query section. I got this error:  
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content,"http://localhost/wordpres' at line 2`  

ANY HELP TO SOLVE THIS ERROR PLEASE???

Comment: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ might help

Answer (score 0):

I've used this plugin many times for exactly what you're describing: https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Answer (score 0):

You should change the URL in the guid column, with this SQL snippet:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'http://localhost/wordpress', 'LIVE URL');
```

Also make sure all the files are online. I'm not a fan of plugins if there is an easy fix for it. And with Wordpress a lot of things can be done without plugins needed.